# Pycharm displays an anomally when running a pygame code

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, display

I am having a weird display when I run a simple Pygame. The game runs perfectly but the screen is weird.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')
pygame.display.update()


x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the screen every frame. Put `pygame.display.update()` inside your `main_loop`, and remove it from original positon:

```
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

This should work